# Prove that the solution of $2^x = 5$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, real-numbers

Given the equation
$$2^x = 5.$$
I want to show that the solution of the equation above is an irrational.

**My Idea:**
First, if we use $\ln$ then we can write
$$x = \frac{\ln 5}{\ln 2}.$$
Finally, we are going to proof that $\frac{\ln 5}{\ln 2}$ is irrational. I stuck at this step.

Second, by assuming $x$ is rational solution of the equation above. So that we can write $x = \frac{p}{q}, p,q \in \mathbb{Q} (p,q) = 1.$ We are going to show the contradiction, but I stuck at this step.

Comment: You don't need to bring logs into this. If $x=m/n$ then multiplying $2^x=5$ on both sides by $2^n$ gives $2^m=5^n$ Now use unique factorization of positive integers. [first note $m,n$ here can be assumed to be positive integers (explain why)].

Comment: I think on the second step you just raise both sides with the power of $n$ (?)

But I understand your idea. It is very clear for me.

Comment: yes each side to n power not 2^n (I erred).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is a solution $x=\frac pq$ where $p,q\in\mathbb Z,q\neq0$.

Then if $2^x=2^{\frac pq}=5$ we can get $2^p=5^q$.

If $p$ and $q$ have different signs then one side is strictly greater than $1$ and one side is strictly less so they can't be equal, so they must have the same sign. So suppose they're positive (or take reciprocals to make them so). Now use the unique factorisation of the naturals to show that these can't be equal, a contradiction so the assumption that there is a rational solution must be false.

Answer (score 2):

If $2^{p}=5^q$ and if $p,q$ are integers then we get a contradiction because (positive) powers of $2$ are even but powers of $5$ are odd.(Alternatively you can use unique factorisation.)

Comment: negative powers of 2 are not "even".

Comment: @cofeemath I think that’s pretty clear. But I have edited. Funny how much people like to nitpick.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku It might be clear to you and me but who are we to say it's clear to everyone. No one's perspective is without bias and perhaps giving help in excess is better than in deficit.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: Keep in mind, our goals on this site are not exactly the same as the goals in an individual teacher/student interaction. So although spoonfeeding your individual student may be unhealthy, sometimes on this site the positive effects of maximal clarity outweigh the negative effects of spoonfeeding. The point is that many people besides the OP can benefit from your answer.